# How can I clear my Netflix recently watched movies list?

Tags: netflix

Is there a way to clear the list of recently watched movies on Netflix?

Comment: This question is VERY outdated. I have an updated Q&A to this question [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79677/quick-way-to-clean-up-netflix-viewing-activity/79678#79678). It not only leads you to how to do it manually (walks you how to get to the viewing activity page), but also gives you the power of *the coder*, and shows you how you can regularly erase your recent activity, using very simple JavaScript that's just ***copy & paste***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently.

I was trying to find an official statement about it, which I'm pretty sure exists since I remember reading about it a while ago, but it seems that the [Netflix help](http://www.netflix.com/Help) has changed and it's hard to find what you are looking for.

A [simple search](http://www.google.com/search?q=netflix+instant+delete+history) reveals a [bunch](http://getsatisfaction.com/netflix/topics/is_there_a_way_to_remove_items_from_your_instant_watch_activity_history) [of](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_clear_your_instant_watching_activity_on_netflix) threads asking for this same feature.

Comment: For people who come here LONG after 2010, I have an updated Q&A to this question [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79677/quick-way-to-clean-up-netflix-viewing-activity/79678#79678). It not only leads you to how to do it manually, but also gives you the power of *the coder*, and shows you how you can regularly erase your recent activity, using very simple JavaScript that's just ***copy & paste***

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the view history from netflix now. This [article](http://mashtips.com/delete-netflix-viewing-history/) worked for me.

Comment: While that link may have the answer, linkrot happens. When that link no longer functions there is no useful information in your post. Please at least summarize the information to be found there (and _do_ link back to the source).

Answer (score -2):

You can remove a film by running it to the end, by dubbing it when it finishes, wait to 
see “rate me” and the picture of the film and then press the backspace key—this should delete it.