# Clearing watch history for television episodes on Netflix

Tags: netflix

I am re-watching the [Arrested Development](http://movies.netflix.com/WiMovie/Arrested_Development_Season_1/70003533?trkid=2361637) TV series through Netflix. Having watched it before, Netflix is showing me my watched history:

[image: Arrested Development, Disc 1]

When I get to the end of an episode and click the "Next episode" button, I usually end up where I left off last time I watched it, which is somewhere in the credits at the end of the episode.

Is there any way to reset or clear the watched history for a DVD so that the episodes each start at the beginning again?

Comment: See Also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/how-can-i-clear-my-netflix-recently-watched-movies-list

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the accepted answer for the other question:

There is no way to do this currently.

I was trying to find an official statement about it, which I'm pretty sure exists since I remember reading about it a while ago, but it seems that the [Netflix help](http://www.netflix.com/Help) has changed and it's hard to find what you are looking for.

A [simple search](http://www.google.com/search?q=netflix+instant+delete+history) reveals a [bunch](http://getsatisfaction.com/netflix/topics/is_there_a_way_to_remove_items_from_your_instant_watch_activity_history) [of](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_clear_your_instant_watching_activity_on_netflix) threads asking for this same feature.

Answer (score 0):

That's not entirely true.  You can now find your history and remove the logs of your viewing. They try to force you manually to click on a lot to remove everything but if you do it will remove your viewing history and revert to showing you starting at the beginning of episodes. I confirmed this on my account.

If you have any semblance of experience with web-programming instead of clicking you can run a jQuery function within the browser console.  For instance, in Chrome, right click on anything  then click on the "Inspect Element" option.  It doesn't matter where on the page you do this. Just make sure your on the netflix page with your history.  In the console type jQuery('.deleteBtn').click(); and click enter.  This command simulates mouseclicks on all your checkboxes to removing everything in your history at once without the annoyance of having to manually scroll down and click on everything. The rows in the table will look like they're updating. If you wait it'll look like the page is hanging but you don't need to let the page reload.  After you follow the steps, give the page about 2-3 seconds then refresh the page-the previously displayed history records should be gone.  Rinse and repeat until all your viewing history is gone.

Note if you want to only do this for one particular series, don't use the above command.  Netflix has a way to remove your history for a particular series in two clicks. Click once to remove an episode, then it gives an option to remove history for an entire series.

Comment: You seem to be responding to a different answer. Please note that this is not a forum and that answers can be sorted in a number of different ways. If you're going to refer to another answer, it's best to link to it. Your answer here should be able to stand alone.